# How can i use popover controller in UIPageViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Can i use the popover controller to get back to previous view controllers in page view controller. Is there any method to do so.

This code i am trying.

```
-(void)goNext
{
Vcontr = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pageController];

if(popoverController == nil){   //make sure popover isn't displayed more than once in the view
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pageController];
}
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

popoverController.delegate = self;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tutorials:

[iPad for iPhone Developers 101: UIPopoverController Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)

[iPad UIPopoverController Video](http://ulapp.us/ipad-app-video-ipad-app-tutorial-uipopovercontroller/)

and read [Apple developers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

and you can find sample code by [Apple developers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Popovers/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIPopoverController *popoverController ;///defin this in the .h

if(popoverController == nil){   //make sure popover isn't displayed more than once in the view
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourPageViewController]; 
}
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

popoverController.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with `nil`.' This error is given.

Comment: did you implement your yourPageViewController in the view didload or any where before calling this?

Comment: i did that in -(id)initWithViewControllers:(NSMutableArray *)Controllers.

Comment: what to do further for this.

Comment: please follow @omarj to get tutorial of how to build your pagecontroll